# Convert powermockito testcase code into testng testcase

Tags: unit-testing, junit, testng, powermockito, testng-eclipse

Here I am using whenNew method  in powermockito.

```
@Test
     public void test() {
        MsgTransmit msgtransmit= mockm(MsgTransmit.class); 
        String userId= id101;     
        Powermockito.whennew(msgtransmit .class).withArgumen("transmit.get_msg",jdbcTemplate).thenReturn(MsgTransmit); 
        Powermockito.when(msgtransmit.res(msg,userId).thenReturn(output);
        Msg.getDetails(userId,msg); 
    }
```

`Powermockito.whenNew(msgtransmit .class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(null);`

How to change whenNew to testng.Can anyone provide some example for this conversion.
And recommend some websites for learning testng.

Comment: To learn testng:
https://testng.org/doc/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/
https://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html
To convert the whenNew method in PowerMockito to TestNG, you can use the @Mock
and then jusr stub with when()
 when(msgTransmit.res(msg, userId)).thenReturn(output);

Comment: Can u show one example of changing whenNew to testng code